# Nginx Redirect for /stargate/index.php?seite=sga

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect (only this special old url)

```
/stargate/index.php?seite=sga
```

with a 301 to

```
/stargate-atlantis-serienubersicht
```

How can I do that?

Thanks
kay899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference query arguments in nginx as `$arg_seite`:

```
location = /stargate/index.php {
  if ($arg_seite = 'sga'){
    return 301 $scheme://your_domain.com/stargate-atlantis-serienubersicht;
  }
  # here goes config for handling that index.php if request came with other parameters
  # or if not needed just:
  return 404;
  # this is important, otherwise will return 404 for both branches
}
```

the above will also rewrite `?seite=sga&some-other-param=123`, if not desired - test the `$args` variable for unparsed params

Comment: Not yet working...  [link](http://www.stargate-project.de/stargate/index.php?seite=sga) shows still ths error: `No input file specified. ` Here is my complete Nginx file: [link](http://laravel.io/bin/d9Djv)

Comment: @kay899 you're getting 404 because nginx needs config for both branches of the `if`, so set some other redirect or `return 404;`

Comment: @kay899 edited the config example, as it turned out also needs `=` in location

Comment: @kay899 change to `location = /stargate/index.php` and move above `location ~ \.php$`, regexes are applied in order so your default php location takes over

Comment: thanks so far. Just corrected it, but not redirecting. Can you have another look in my Nginx file: [link](http://laravel.io/bin/xK6dQ)

Comment: @kay899 does nginx reload with no error? (`sudo nginx -s reload`) may need a space before parentheses after `if`

Comment: with the space before parentheses its working now. Thanks!